# Multi Page Form javascript submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I found this multi page form made with javascript here http://xoxco.com/projects/code/multipage/.
It's the best thing I found since I'm not experienced with javascript but now my problem is how do I take the submit button and link that to a php file to process the request?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function() {
        $('#multipage').multipage();
        $('form').submit(function(){
            alert("Submitted!");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's the script file for the html.
Like where would I put the method?

Also, is there anyway to make it so when I have a email field, for the javascript to validate it since html5 can't.

Comment: This answers your first question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029703/jquery-using-ajax-to-send-data-and-save-in-php --- HTML can validate email, just use (<input type="email">)

Answer (score 0):

You can do an ajax call to your php script. Here probably you will use a POST request since you might want to store the form info into your database.
In HTML5, if your input type is email, then it will be automatically validated. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605773/html5-email-validation) for more info.